# How to add a domain to a Many2one field in Odoo?

Tags: odoo

I have a custom module to manage students and groups, each group has a list of members (student_ids) and a president (manager_id). The manager should be selected among the list of members. So was traying to add a domain to manager_id field domain="[('id','in',self.student_ids.ids)], so the user can only select a manager from the existing list of students. But that code is giving me an error. What should I do to add that domain to the manager_id field?

```
class Groups(models.Model):
    _name = 'estudiantes.group'
    _description = 'Permite manejar los grupos a los que pertenecen los estudiantes'

    manager_id = fields.Many2one('estudiantes.student',string='Responsable', domain="[('id','in',self.student_ids.ids)]")
    student_ids = fields.Many2many('estudiantes.student', string='Estudiantes')
```

Comment: For `in` operation the value should be a set with in ().

Comment: I dont understand, could you be more specific and give me code example. I am new with odoo

Answer (score 0):

`self` is undefined, you can't use it. You should see the following error:

```
NameError: name 'self' is not defined
```

You do not need to specify the `ids` attribute when using an `x2many` field in the domain, it will be evaluated to a list of `ids` and if you do that Odoo will raise the following error message:

```
AttributeError: object has no attribute 'ids'
```

You have just to specify the field name:

```
domain="[('id', 'in', student_ids)]"
```